# JSON形式のポストデータをコンソール画面上に表示させるためにはどうすれば良いでしょうか？

Tags: javascript, php, json, promise

いつもお世話になっています。
下記の質問についてご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたらご教示を願います。

---

#### 【質問の主旨】

下記のPHPとJavaScriptのコードを用いて、`fetch_json.php`にアクセスした時のコンソール画面に、「こんにちは echizenya さん」と表示させるためにはどうすれば良いでしょうか?

- [PHP](https://github.com/echizenyayota/ch10/blob/master/fetch_json.php)

```
<?php
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
print('こんにちは' . $data->name . 'さん！');
```

- [JavaScript](https://github.com/echizenyayota/ch10/blob/master/scripts/fetch_json.js)

```
let data = { mid: 'y001', name: 'echizenya', age: 43};

// JSON
fetch('fetch_json.php', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'content-type':  'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
})
    .then(function(response) {
        return response.text();
    })
    .then(function(text) {
        console.log(text);
    });
```

#### 【質問の補足】

【質問の主旨】に対して下記の4点を補足説明します。

1.
現在、ローカル開発環境上で`fetch_json.php`を実行すると下記の画面が表示されます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

表示された画面の特徴として以下の3点が挙げられます。

- `Notice: Trying to get property of non-object`と注意文が表示される
- `fetch_json.js`で使っている`data`の`name`プロパティの`echizenya`が画面に表示されない。
- コンソール画面には何も表示されない

2.

`fetch_json.php`で`Notice: Trying to get property of non-object`とありますが、dataオブジェクトに対するnameプロパティは、`fetch_json.js`の1行目で定義されていると思います。

3.
ローカル開発環境はWockerを使用しています。
https://wocker.dev/

4.
今回の質問は、「JavaScript逆引きレシピ 第2版」のP483の内容に基づいて投稿しています。

https://www.shoeisha.co.jp/book/detail/9784798157573

---

以上、ご確認のほどよろしくお願い申し上げます。

Comment: GitHubに貼られたコードは分量も短いものなので、できれば直接この質問文に含めてもらった方が見る人に親切かなと思いました。質問文は後からでも [編集] できます。

Comment: cubickさん。アドバイスありがとうございます。コードを質問投稿文に直接記述しました。

Comment: コードを見るか限り、そもそもfetch_json.phpはブラウザから直接開く想定ではないと思います。fetch_json.js はどうやって実行していますか。

Comment: int32_tさん。
コメントありがとうございます。fetch_json.jsも[質問に投稿した同じローカル開発環境](http://takaiba.net/stackoverflow/stackoverflow20190319_1.png)で実行しようとしています。アドレスは、http://wocker.test/js_recipe_v2/ch10/scripts/fetch_json.js です。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

「JavaScript逆引きレシピ」でどのように説明されているか知りませんが、コードから読み取れる意図で回答いたします。

#### `fetch_json.php`をブラウザで開くとエラーになるのはなぜか

このコードはブラウザで直接URLを入力して開かれることを想定してません。`get_file_contents('php://input')`してますから、`<form action=...>`, XHR, fetch などで POST リクエストを送らないと何もデータを持ちません。

#### `fetch_json.js`を実行するには

ブラウザでJavaScriptリソースのURLを直接開いてもコードは実行されません。HTMLページなどからJavaScriptリソースを読み込む必要があります。

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script src="fetch_json.js"></script>
<p>コンソールを開いて見てね</p>
```

この内容で`fetch_json.js` と同じディレクトリにHTMLファイルを置き、そのURLをブラウザから開きます。

もしくは、Node.js などブラウザ以外の環境で`fetch_json.js`を実行する想定なのかもしれません。

Comment: int32_t さん。
コメントありがとうございます。[fetch_json.html](https://github.com/echizenyayota/ch10/commit/5e6a8e61adab13b3cdec69597f6e89f449228f71#diff-d67a2c54a969b1c98661a4ad28d305a6)を新たに作成すると、
意図通りの[動作](http://takaiba.net/stackoverflow/stacjoverflow20190320.png)ができるようになりました！今後ともどうぞよろしくお願いします。